# Error passing JSON object from WebMethod (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have a C# WebMethod that gets some data from my SQL database and then turns it into a JSON string.

Here is the WebMethod

```
    [WebMethod]
    public object getCustomers() {

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Indigo2.Properties.Settings.Constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT custid, cust_name FROM [dbo].[customers] WHERE archive = 'No'"))

            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                List<Customers> customers = new List<Customers>();
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        customers.Add(new Customers
                        {
                            custid = sdr["custid"].ToString(),
                            cust_name = sdr["cust_name"].ToString(),

                    });
                    }
                    con.Close();

                    String result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers);
                    this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    this.Context.Response.Write(result);

                    return result;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

I am them trying to pass this data on the client side, using JavaScript.

Here is my JS

```
    function buildSelect(response) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(response));

        var $tulem = $("<select><option value=''>All</option></select>");

        $.each(JSON.parse(response).rows, function (i, item) {
            $("<option></option>", { value: item.custid })
                .text(item.custid)
                .appendTo($tulem);
        });

        return $tulem;
    }
```

The JSON.Parse fails with following errors

XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: https://localhost:44338/WebService1.asmx/getCustomers
Line Number 1, Column 1: getCustomers:1:1
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 722 of the JSON data

If I return my JSON the console it looks like this.

```
"[{\"custid\":\"ACC001\",\"cust_name\":\"Accenda Limited\"},{\"custid\":\"ANI001\",\"cust_name\":\"Animal Friends\"},{\"custid\":\"APP001\",\"cust_name\":\"Appello\"},{\"custid\":\"ATL001\",\"cust_name\":\"Atlas Contract Furniture\"},{\"custid\":\"BNS001\",\"cust_name\":\"BNS Ltd\"},{\"custid\":\"HAR001\",\"cust_name\":\"Harrow Health\"},{\"custid\":\"IND001\",\"cust_name\":\"Indigo Integrated Solutions\"},{\"custid\":\"MER001\",\"cust_name\":\"Merton Health Limited\"},{\"custid\":\"POL001\",\"cust_name\":\"Polyhose (UK) Ltd\"},{\"custid\":\"PUR001\",\"cust_name\":\"Purbeck School\"},{\"custid\":\"QUE001\",\"cust_name\":\"Queen Elizabeth's School\"},{\"custid\":\"SER001\",\"cust_name\":\"Serbus Limited\"},{\"custid\":\"STS001\",\"cust_name\":\"STS Defence\"},{\"custid\":\"WIM001\",\"cust_name\":\"Wimborne Academy Trust\"}]<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<anyType xmlns:q1=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" d1p1:type=\"q1:string\" xmlns:d1p1=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">[{\"custid\":\"ACC001\",\"cust_name\":\"Accenda Limited\"},{\"custid\":\"ANI001\",\"cust_name\":\"Animal Friends\"},{\"custid\":\"APP001\",\"cust_name\":\"Appello\"},{\"custid\":\"ATL001\",\"cust_name\":\"Atlas Contract Furniture\"},{\"custid\":\"BNS001\",\"cust_name\":\"BNS Ltd\"},{\"custid\":\"HAR001\",\"cust_name\":\"Harrow Health\"},{\"custid\":\"IND001\",\"cust_name\":\"Indigo Integrated Solutions\"},{\"custid\":\"MER001\",\"cust_name\":\"Merton Health Limited\"},{\"custid\":\"POL001\",\"cust_name\":\"Polyhose (UK) Ltd\"},{\"custid\":\"PUR001\",\"cust_name\":\"Purbeck School\"},{\"custid\":\"QUE001\",\"cust_name\":\"Queen Elizabeth's School\"},{\"custid\":\"SER001\",\"cust_name\":\"Serbus Limited\"},{\"custid\":\"STS001\",\"cust_name\":\"STS Defence\"},{\"custid\":\"WIM001\",\"cust_name\":\"Wimborne Academy Trust\"}]</anyType>"
```

What am I doing wrong, what can I do to change this into a standard clean JSON string?

UPDATED

This is where the WebMethod is called from, its the dataURL, for a field called cust_name, defined in the editoptions of a JQGRID.

```
        jQuery("#jqquotes").jqGrid({
            url: '../We

bService1.asmx/getDataQuotes',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'POST',
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
                    if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
                    if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
                    if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    root: function (obj) {
                        return typeof obj.d.rows === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d.rows) : obj.d.rows;
                    },
                    page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
                    total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
                    records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; },
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                loadComplete: function () {
                    $('#jqquoteitems').trigger('reloadGrid');

                },
                loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                        'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +
                        'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                    alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                },
                onSelectRow: function () {
                    showDetailsGrid();
                },
                height: 'auto',
                //autowidth: true,
                rowNum: 5,
                rowList: [5, 10, 15],
                colNames: ['Doc ID', 'Quote #', 'Summary', 'Date', 'Customer', 'Contact', 'custid'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'docid', key: true, index: 'docid', width: 55, editable: true },
                    { name: 'quote_number', index: 'quote_number', width: 45, editable: true },
                    { name: 'summary', index: 'summary', width: 160, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea' },
                    {
                        name: 'quote_date', formatter: 'date', datefmt: "d-m-Y", editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                        formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s", newformat: "d-m-Y" }, index: 'quote_date', width: 60, editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'cust_name', index: 'cust_name', width: 140, align: "left", editable: true, edittype: "select",
                        editoptions: {
                            dataUrl: '/WebService1.asmx/getCustomers',
                            buildSelect: buildSelect
                        }
                    },
```

...

Comment: Do you realize that you have xml content right after the json array? `\"Wimborne Academy Trust\"}]<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>`

Comment: How do you request your API? Can you please add the code for that?

Comment: The json you are getting on client side js is wrong because it has both json and xml. Can you show the code where the ajax or api request is sent from js to the web method getCustomers.

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because the end of your JSON string you have `"<anyType>"` which is not a parseable for JSON.